# Firebase 502 Bad Gateway on Storage dashboard

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Recently our downloads through Firebase Storage started failing with a 502 Bad Gateway error.

We first noticed this in our apps, but later found out that the same error occurs when trying to download any file through the Firebase Storage dashboard.
When trying to download the same file directly through the Google Cloud Console it works fine, no errors. This happened with all our Firebase projects.

I've already checked our access rules, service account permissions and it all seems to be right.

Is there any way for me to find out why is this error happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to enable and check access logs on your Firebase Storage. To do that, you would need to use **Audit logs**.

1. Head on to your Cloud Console then you would need to access to IAM & Admin > [Audit Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit).
2. In the Audit Logs page, find or filter `Cloud Storage for Firebase API` and `Google Cloud Storage`.
3. Change the configuration in order to start logging actions (I would suggest to enable the three options `Admin Read`, `Data Read`, `Data Write`). You can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access?config-console#config-console) if you need more information about how to activate them.

After configuring the audit logs, try to access or download files from the Firebase Storage and Google Cloud Storage. You may view the `data read` logs on  Logging > [Logs Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs), in here you need to select your service, find **Resource Type** and select the **GCS Bucket**. You can now see all the Cloud Storage logs that you configured on the Audit Logs.

If you still can't get to know why the error happens after checking the logs, I would suggest that you contact [**Firebase Support**](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to be able to assist you further on your concern.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the detailed answer. 
I've tried checking the logs but there were no errors there. There were also no logs for `Cloud Storage for Firebase API`, which is I think is strange.
I'm already contacting support, but it isn't looking very promising.

Comment: Well, it seems to be related with custom metadata on storage files. Not sure why though. 
Just uploaded some files without this custom metadata and it worked. Also works when removing it directly from Google Cloud Storage.
Might be a Firebase issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems related with custom metadata on storage files. I managed to solve it by replacing blanks with underscore in metadata parameters name, e.g. "user name" caused 502 error but "user_name" works fine. I guess this happend after some recent firebase library update.